# Why do I see Null in the output from my function?

Tags: evaluation

I've seen some comments relating to this topic but I am new and they are not really helpful. Please look at the following two outputs. One has an

```
If[*something*, Print["yes"], Print["no"].
```

First strange thing is that `"yes"` is printed properly, but is not an output normally (`Output[41]= ...`). However, my bigger problem are the NULL's.  With the exact same expression, but instead using brackets for my "true" statement; e.g.,

```
If[*something*, {Print["yes"], Print["OK"]}, Print["no"]
```

Now I still have the `"yes"` and `"OK"` printed, still not as outputs, but also a `{NULL, NULL}` printed in the output.  Is there not some simple way of handling this so that I get:

```
Out[41]= yes
Out[42]= OK
```

Very simple code below.

```
In[30]:= f[x_] := 2^x - 1

In[31]:= n = 2
Out[31]= 2

In[32]:= m = 3
Out[32]= 3

In[33]:= q = 0
Out[33]= 0

In[34]:= g[y_, z_] := If[Mod[f[y], z] == 0, Print["yes"], Print["no"]]

In[35]:= g[2, 3]
```

> `yes`

**Compare with**

```
In[36]:= f[x_] := 2^x - 1

In[37]:= n = 2
Out[37]= 2

In[38]:= m = 3
Out[38]= 3

In[39]:= q = 0
Out[39]= 0

In[40]:= g[y_, z_] := 
           If[Mod[f[y], z] == 0, {Print["yes"], Print["OK"]}, Print["no"]]

 In[41]:= g[2, 3]
```

> `yes`
>   `OK`

```
 Out[41]= {Null, Null}
```

Comment: `Print` returns `Null`. So what you see is the expected output. In the first example you did not have a LIST, so that is what you did not see the NULL. In the second case, you had a LIST {,} so that is why you saw the NULL's in there. Mathematica had to put the NULL's in the list.

Comment: just compare `{Print["foo"]}` with `Print["foo"]` to see.

Comment: The way to handle it is to not use `Print` -- there's no need for it. Just `"yes"` instead of `Print["yes"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Good advice about not using `Print` to return values from functions because functions always return the result of their last evaluation as already been given. You also need a heightened awareness of the special way in which `If` is evaluated.

Consider the following extract from a notebook:

[image: notebook_page]

At the top of notebook page, I have asked Mathematica for information about `If`. What is returns is illuminating. Note that it shows only two valid forms of `If`; one with three arguments and one with four arguments. This suggests that the two argument form you used might be questionable. It also tells us that `If` has the attribute `HoldRest`, which means that Mathematica handles arguments two through four in a non-standard way; they are passed to `If` unevaluated.

In the rest of the notebook I investigate how `If` handles being called with different argument counts, from one up to four.

The first thing we see it that, unsurprisingly, `If` won't take just one argument. When I try that, the code editor warns me (notice the red carat after `True`). However, I stubbornly proceed and attempt to evaluate the expression only to get an error message and the expression returned unevaluated. The error message, however, is informative in that it says

> between 2 and 4 arguments expected

So we have learned the two argument form is acceptable even if the documentation ignores it. I then proceed to take a harder look this form. I experience what you report in your question. Given `True`, `If` returns `"OK"`; given `False`, it appears to return nothing.

But this isn't so. The Mathematica front-end is simply hiding the what was returned. But we can make the returned value visible by requesting the evaluation be shown in its full (internal) form, as in the next evaluation I make.

What happens in the two argument case is that the missing argument is replaced by `Null`. This is the what Mathematica normally does with missing arguments.

The next to last evaluation shows how using the full four argument form gives complete control over what is returned. The four argument form will never surprise you.

The final evaluation highlights the pitfalls of the two argument form. Notice that a non-Boolean 1st argument will result in non-evaluation.

Some morals can be drawn from this little discourse:

- The two argument form of `If` can be used, but there are risks. I would say it's OK to use it when you fully understand how `If` works.
- Use the full four argument form in situations where `If` must evaluate and return a result without fail.
- Mathematica can be used to investigate how Mathematica works.